# Composite index creation in DB2

Tags: db2

I used to create composite `index` for my `Oracle` table with the following script.

`CREATE INDEX index_name ON my_table    (column1,column2,column3)    TABLESPACE tablespace_name;`

When I tried the same in `DB2`, got some errors at `tablespace` and I tried using the following script simply,

`CREATE INDEX index_name ON my_table    (column1,column2,column3);`

Is this fine in `DB2`? As I am new to `DB2` and no syntax found when searched for a composite index in `DB2`, not sure about this. Need advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the CREATE INDEX documentation, you can check the InfoCenter: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000919.html

The DB2 CREATE INDEX sentence you provided is correct. Remember that in DB2, you do not provide the tablespace at index creation. The tablespace for indexes is specified when you create the table

```
CREATE TABLE XX
 (
 ...
 )
IN ts_table
INDEX IN ts_indexes
```

For more information about the create table, please take a look at this: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html

Comment: This is a platform specific answer for DB2 LUW. For those who have DB2 for i see http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzintro.htm

Comment: @WarrenT we should ask the platform, and re-tag the questions. I found that there is a tag called db2400, I think it should be called db2i. Also, I did not see any tag for DB2 for zOS.

Comment: Also note that you *can* specify a tablespace in the `CREATE INDEX` statement if you are using range partitioned tables.  Some have noted that you can create a table with a single range partition specifically so that you can create each index in a separate tablespace.